# Deploy password policy for Cloud m365 accounts

Tags: password-policy, microsoft-365

Does anyone know how to deploy a password policy in a 100% M365 cloud user environment?

Comment: **Microsoft cloud-only accounts have a pre-defined password policy that cannot be changed. The only items you can change are the number of days until a password expires and whether or not passwords expire at all.** - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/misc/password-policy-recommendations?view=o365-worldwide